# Flutter Auto Router package with back swap gesture

Tags: ios, flutter, gesture, back

hey im using flutter auto router package in my app and i want to add the swap gesture to go back between pages,tried couple of things but nothing worked.

```
this is the main.dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  AppRouter appRouter = AppRouter();
  return FlutterSizer(builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
      return MaterialApp.router(
        themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
        theme: ThemeData.light(),
        darkTheme: ThemeData.light(),
        routerConfig: appRouter.config(),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

tried couple of packeges and tried wrapping my material with gesture and some builders.